# node-ipc client couldnt accept data from pipe(which c++ send) and echo error Messages are large, You may want to consider smaller messages?

Tags: node-ipc

node-ipc  client couldnt accept data from pipe(which c++ send) and echo error Messages are large, You may want  to consider smaller messages?

But actually I did send a very small message like this:

```json
{
  "data":{"timestamp":"1111111...1111"},
  "type":"message"
}
```

I can use this client send message to my server which written by c++.
By I couldnt accept any message from my server.

Answer (score 1):

node-ipc need a \f following the json.

so if you use c++ or other languages, just send the message like this:

```
{ "type": "message", "data": { "foo": "bar" } } \f
```

this is the issue of node-ipc:

- https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/issues/79
- https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/issues/178
- https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/issues/157
- https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/issues/66